# HTML5 Drop Down Menu with output

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, web

I am creating a website using HTML5 and CSS. I am trying to create a drop down menu, which I have the code for. However, my code just produces a drop down menu. How do I add a "go" button, so that when an option is selected and the go button is pressed, an answer is outputted that relates to the drop down menu value.

EXAMPLE, I HAVE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo">1</option>
            <option value="saab">2</option>
            <option value="mercedes">3</option>
            <option value="audi">4</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

HOW DO I:
1. Add a submit button.
2. When the button is submited, and a number is chosen from the drop down menu, the car name is outputted for the user to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way.

Put an id on your select. For example:

```
<select id="carNames">
```

Make a button with an onclick JavaScript function call.

```
<button onclick="showCarName();" >Go</button>
```

Here where it gets fun. In JavaScript script tags define a function that gets the value of your select.

```
function showCarName(){
      //First grab your select
    var select = document.getElementById("carNames");
      //Then get it's value
    var carName = select.value;
      //After that you just need to write it somewhere in the document
    document.write(carName);
}
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood your code, but i'm not using JavaScript, just HTML5 and CSS. Can I only create this kind of drop down menu using JavaScript?

Comment: Yes you're going to need JavaScript or Php or something that can run scripts.